# Mutate a list of object in FaunaDB

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, faunadb

I have my GraphQL schema imported in FaunaDB and want to create a new question

```
type Choices {
  key: String!
  value: String!
  question: Question
}

type Question {
  title: String!
  snippet: String
  choices: [Choices!]! @relation
  answer: String!
  explanation: String!
}

type Query {
  allQuestions: [Question!]!
}
```

To do so, I'm using axios and have my GraphQL mutation like that:

```
const CREATE_QUESTION = `
mutation($title: String!, $explanation: String!, $snippet: String, $answer: String!, $choices: [ChoicesInput]!) {
  createQuestion(data: {
    title: $title
    explanation: $explanation,
    snippet: $snippet,
        answer: $answer,
    choices: {
      create: $choices
    }
  }) {
    _id
    explanation
    answer
    title
    snippet
    choices {
      data {
        key
        value
      }
    }
  }
}
`
```

Everything work except for the choices, I want to send an array of object but got the error:

`` Variable '$choices' expected value of type '[ChoicesInput]!' but got: "[ { key: 'A', value: '`0 1 2` and `0 1 2`' }, { key: 'B', value: '`0 1 2` and `3 3 3`' }, { key: 'C', value: '`3 3 3` and `0 1 2`' } ]". Reason: '[0]' Expected 'ChoicesInput', found not an object. (line 2, column 86): mutation($title: String!, $explanation: String!, $snippet: String, $answer: String!, $choices: [ChoicesInput]!) { ^ ``

What should I make differently to be able to send my array of objects?

Comment: It sounds like you are passing a string, not an array of objects, as the value for $choices. Its not clear from your question how the variables are passed to your axios. Please show all relevant code

Comment: This is the call `
const result = await axios({
    url: "https://graphql.fauna.com/graphql",
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.FAUNA_SERVER_SECRET}`
    },
    data: {
      query,
      variables
    }
  })
`

Comment: Please edit your question. We'd need to see how you're actually constructing the variables object and specifically the choices property of it.